TextInput blinking / flickering when I format text in `onChangeText` React Native
I'm trying a simple example of dynamic input formatting if input = 3 => save text, else - text old:
const [text, setText] = useState('');

return(
    <View>
        <TextInput
            value={text}
            onChangeText={innerText => {
                if (innerText === '3')
                    setText(innerText);
                }}
        />
    </View>)

What happens:
I enter anything, try to correct the input - I get the input blinking for a few seconds - the value that I enter from the keyboard appears for a moment, then returns to the previous state, thanks to the "filter" in onChangeText (for example, you can enter only the number 3, and when entering the rest - I actually see all the characters that I enter for some time, and only then they are erased in accordance with the value).
How to avoid this?
How to avoid this? I tried a bunch of ways:

changing onChangeText to onChange
changing onChangeText to onKeyPress
and all their combinations
two states connected via useEffect (the first was set in value, the second was set in onChangeText, and in useEffect I equated them)
defaultValue does not suit my tasks
maxLength does not suit my tasks, as well as editable = false
MaskInput has the same problem when the mask ends and you try to enter something longer than its length
react-native-text-input-mask and react-native-advanced-input-mask work well for me, because they are direct wrappers over native inputs (a wrapper over a native input would be perfect for me), but in the first one my customNotations crash on Android, and in the second one if I open <Modal>, then my value disappears, as if the value is empty, although I made a <Text> component next to it that duplicates the value, and the value itself is fine, it is simply reset inside the component, and if I use defaultValue, then onChangeText will be called twice, which greatly breaks the processing logic
I'm desperate, what should I do with this, please tell me! I need something that will help process and replace user input BEFORE it is displayed


Please check

@ShehanLakshitha I have seen this, it does not solve the problem, and I have written a simple example that reproduces the problem and does not contain any third-party logic, just to isolate the problem
